# Calculate some statistics with Math.Net

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, mathnet-numerics

I have some results that are stored in a multidimensional array:

```
double[,] results;
```

Each column is a time series of prices for a specific variable (e.g. "house", "car", "electricity"). I would like to calculate some statistics for each variable so that to summarize the results in a more compact form.
For example, I was looking at the percentile function in Math.Net.

I would like to calculate the 90th percentile of the prices for each column (so for each variable).

I am trying the following, since the function doesn't work on multidimensional array (so I cannot pass results[,] as argument for the percentile function):

```
for (int i = 0, i <= results.GetLength(2), i++)
{
    myList.Add(MathNet.Numerics.Statistics.Statistics.Percentile(results[,i], 90));
}
```

So I want to loop through the columns of my results[,] and calculate the 90th percentile, adding the result to a list. 
But this doesn't work because of wrong syntax in results[, i]. There is no other (more clear) error message unfortunately.

Can you help me understand where the problem is and if there's a better way to calculate a percentile by column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Percentile](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Statistics/Statistics.htm#Percentile) is an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) with following [calling sequence](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/Statistics/Statistics.cs):

> ```
> public static double Percentile(this IEnumerable<double> data, int p)
> ```

So you can use Linq to transform your 2d array into an appropriate sequence to pass to `Percentile`.

However, `results.GetLength(2)` will throw an exception because the [dimension argument of `GetLength()` is zero-based](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You *probably* meant `results.GetLength(1)`.  Assuming that's what you meant, you can do:

```
        var query = Enumerable.Range(0, results.GetLength(1))
            .Select(iCol => Enumerable.Range(0, results.GetLength(0))
                .Select(iRow => results[iRow, iCol])
                .Percentile(90));
```

You can have Linq make the list for you,

```
        var myList= query.ToList();
```

or add it to a pre-existing list:

```
        myList.AddRange(query);
```

**update**

To filter `NaN` values use [`double.IsNaN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264491.aspx):

```
        var query = Enumerable.Range(0, results.GetLength(1))
            .Select(iCol => Enumerable.Range(0, results.GetLength(0))
                .Select(iRow => results[iRow, iCol])
                .Where(d => !double.IsNaN(d))
                .Percentile(90));
```

**update**

If one extracts a couple of array extensions:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Columns<T>(this T[,] array)
    {
        if (array == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(1))
            .Select(iCol => Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0))
                .Select(iRow => array[iRow, iCol]));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Rows<T>(this T[,] array)
    {
        if (array == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0))
            .Select(iRow => Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(1))
                .Select(iCol => array[iRow, iCol]));
    }
}
```

Them the query becomes:

```
        var query = results.Columns().Select(col => col.Where(d => !double.IsNaN(d)).Percentile(90));
```

which seems much clearer.

Comment: Wow this works nicely. But I am getting some NaN in the results. This might be because of some NaN in the time series. How can I modify the query to avoid this NaN? Thank you.

Comment: @mickG - Filter with `double.IsNan()`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. This all work as expected.